# Find the approximate probability of randomly choosing $40$ of the $1000$ applicants and only $12$ women are selected.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

**STATEMENT:** Erica is working on a project using software to find probabilities. She quickly realizes that her software cannot calculate some of the large factorials needed in finding some of the probabilities. For example, at a factory, $1000$ people applied for $40$ available positions. Even though $450$ of the applicants were women, only $12$ women were hired. She needs to find the probability of this occurring by random chance. Of course, realistically, she would probably want to find the probability of choosing at most 12 women.

**QUESTION:** Find the approximate probability of randomly choosing $40$ of the $1000$ applicants and only $12$ women are selected. You should find the approximate probability without using large factorials like $1000!$

**MY WORKING:**

If the woman is selected then it is success. Let $p$ be probability of success, then $p=\frac{12}{450}=0.0266$. Total Number of trials are given by $n=40$.

I know that poisson distribution can be used to approximate binomial distribution, whenever $n$ is large and $p$ is small (in this case $p=0.0266$). In this case, $n=40$ which isn't a large number. The question asks to approximate probability without using large numbers. I don't understand what that means, because I don't see any large number OR may be my way of approaching problem through poisson approximation isn't correct.

Does anyone have an idea on how do I tackle this? Any guidance will be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just do it exactly?  What's the probability that $0$ women are chosen?  $1$ woman? And so on up to $12$, then just add.

Comment: You mean this way? The probability of choosing $1$ woman is $1-\frac{1}{450}$, the probability of choosing $2$ women will be $(1-\frac{1}{450})×(1-\frac{2}{249})$. Hence the probability of choosing $12$ women will be $(1-\frac{1}{450})×(1-\frac{2}{249})...×(1-\frac{12}{238})$

Comment: Note:  I don't understand your attempt.  We know the probability that an individual woman is selected (assuming randomness), it is $.04$  So you could a normal approximation with that probability, if you liked.  Or you could use Poisson, with a mean of $.04\times 450=18$

Comment: No, that is not the probability of choosing $1$ woman. I don't understand your computation at all.

Comment: Yes I got your point. It can be done with poisson using the mean $18$, but I don't understand how the probability of an individual woman to be selected is $0.04$?

Comment: Because $\frac {40}{1000}=.04$ is the portion of the population which is hired.  If the hiring were random, you'd therefore expect that each person was hired with probability $.04$

Comment: This question is missing a very important piece of information.  Find the probably that only 12 women were hired assuming the probability that "...".  The "..." is  missing.  The question makes no probabilistic assumptions.

Comment: Should add:  how you read the problem makes a big difference.  Given the intent to use a simple analytic approximation, I assumed independence but that is not stated.   One could also read the problem as assuming that the goal was to hire exactly $40$ people.  That yields a significantly different result.

Answer (score 1):

$p($selecting a woman$)$ is an approximately constant value of $0.45$ at each choice.

Let $X$ be the total number of women selected out of $40.$ Then, $X\sim B(40,0.45).$

$p(X=12) = \ldots$

$p(X\leq 12) = \ldots$

My experience tells me that these values should be within a $20$% error range of the exact value - or maybe less - which means that the answer you get from this calculation is a good enough *approximation*.